# Android exoplayer how i can set the resolution of the video?

Tags: android, exoplayer, screen-resolution, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

i am using exoplayer library in my android tv application, i need to make the resolution of the video better , i tried to set setMAxVideoSize(1920,1080) but not working, also trying to set the minimunBitrate value to Integer.Max_value but not working also

below is my code

```
    player.setTrackSelectionParameters(
            player.getTrackSelectionParameters()
                    .buildUpon()
                    .setPreferredAudioLanguages(languages)
                    .setPreferredTextLanguage("ar")
                    .setMaxVideoSize(1920, 1080)
                    .setMinVideoSize(1920, 1080)
                    .setMinVideoBitrate(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .setMaxVideoBitrate(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, what's the resolution of the actual video that you're trying do display? Is it actually 1080p? And what's the bitrate?

No matter what settings you use, you can't make it have a higher resolution or bitrate than what the video actually has

Comment: Yes the video has resolution 1920 1080 retuned by gettrackgroup and track format the problem is the code above doesnt make this resolution selected by default ...

Comment: can i play high resolution to low or medium resolution video in exoplayer

Comment: Can i make thr resolution lower than the actual video resolutio ?? I tried setvideoSize but it keep load the bigger resolution...i need to lower it @user496854